# Regex not giving proper result because of special character

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have input like this :

```
Helio P10 processor ARM® cortex®-A53™1.8GHz
```

and using regex : `(?i)(Cortex)\\s*-{0,}\\s*(A)?\\s*-{0,}\\s*(\\d{1,2})?`

for input eg. `Helio P10 processor ARM cortex-A53 1.8GHz`
it gives proper value - `cortex-A53`

but for input eg. `Helio P10 processor ARM® cortex®-A53™1.8GHz` it doesnt work properly and gives `cortex` as output.

**Requirement :** To extract values like cortex-A54 but if any special character comes between cortex and - it doesn't work.

Comment: It returns `cortex` in both cases (actually, I see the same 2 strings here). What are the pattern requirements?

Comment: And what is the goal ? Your question ?

Comment: sorry updated my question now.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/sHJmLM/2, but without exact requirements, we can guess forever.

Comment: If it is in java probably when you manipulate strings you are losing the utf characters somewhere and it's not the regex that is problematic. Give us some code maybe to look at

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
String s = "Helio P10 processor ARM cortex-A53 1.8GHz"+
        "Helio P10 processor ARM® cortex®-A53™1.8GHz"+
        "Helio P10 processor ARM® Cortex®-A72™1.8GHz";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i:(?<proc>cortex)(?:.?)-(?<ref>[a-zA-Z]\\d{1,2}))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group("proc")+"-"+m.group("ref"));
}
```

Regex explanation:

- `(?<proc>cortex)`: Detect the begin of your wanted result
- `(?:.?)`: Allow a special char after cortex
- `(?<ref>[a-zA-Z]\d{1,2})`: The format of wanted data after cortex
- `(?i:...)`: Ignore case

Output:

```
cortex-A53
cortex-A53
Cortex-A72
```